# Codeigniter count_all_results() and result() with group_by, join, where vs

Tags: codeigniter, group-by

I want to do query both result and count with group_by.

```
$id= 2;
$limit = 10;
$offset = ($id - 1) * $limit;
$this->db->group_by('BE.etiket_id');
$this->db->from('bulten_icerigi_etiketler as BE');
$this->db->join('etiketler as E', 'BE.etiket_id=E.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('bulten_icerigi as BI', 'BE.bulten_id=BI.id', 'left');
$count = $this->db->count_all_results('', false);
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$this->db->order_by('E.adi');
$results = $this->db->get()->result();
```

However, I have error

```
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'tbl_`E.adi' in 'field list'
```

Can I use count_all_results() and result() together ?

Thank you.

Comment: Where's **'tbl_'E.adi'**? Show another code, which contains this line.  It's hard to understand how does this error refers to your query. Seems that you've use a column name which doesn't exists in the table.

Comment: My code in my model.
It will show filter count and data list.

My error :

`A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column tbl_E.adi in field list
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, tbl_E.adi, tbl_E.id FROM tbl_bulten_icerigi_etiketler as BE LEFT JOIN tbl_etiketler as E ON BE.etiket_id=E.id LEFT JOIN tbl_bulten_icerigi as BI ON BE.bulten_id=BI.id GROUP BY BE.etiket_id ORDER BY E.adi
Filename: C:/Users/Hilal Gür/Documents/Project/elika_web/system/database/DB_driver.php`

Comment: Replace `tbl_E.adi` with `E.adi`. But I can't see where you're using this `tbl_E.adi` in your query. It's definitely another query. You should present another one.

Comment: Why does `tbl_` attaches to each table name???

Comment: My tables have prefix tbl_... I defined them in db class. It is not important actually.
My problem is count_all_result() with group_by.
When I delete `$this->db->group_by(BE.etiket_id);` code my code is working . I have to use group_by.

Comment: You should look at [this](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-group-by.php) and [this](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/group-by). You can't `group by` column which you didn't selected in `select`. Try to use `E.adi` and `E.id` instead of `BE.etiket_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `group by` columns which you didn't selected in `select`.

Try to use `E.adi` and `E.id` instead of `BE.etiket_id` in your `group by`.
Your query should looks like:

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(*) as count, 
     tbl_E.adi, 
     tbl_E.id 
FROM tbl_bulten_icerigi_etiketler as BE 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_etiketler as E ON BE.etiket_id=E.id 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_bulten_icerigi as BI ON BE.bulten_id=BI.id 
GROUP BY tbl_E.adi, tbl_E.id    // here you need to change 
ORDER BY tbl_E.adi
```

```
$this->db->group_by(array("E.adi", "E.id"));
```

Comment: I changed select option. It worked.
I think my problem is "E.id" or "E.adi" in select() option. It is not allow "table_name.id" with group_by(). 

`$this->db->select('COUNT(*) as count, adi');
$this->db->group_by('etiket_id');
$this->db->from('bulten_icerigi_etiketler as BE');
$this->db->join('etiketler as E', 'BE.etiket_id=E.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('bulten_icerigi as BI', 'BE.bulten_id=BI.id', 'left');
$count = $this->db->count_all_results('', false);
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$this->db->order_by('adi');
$results = $this->db->get()->result();`

Comment: @HilalGÜR, you didn't presented your table columns, but, yes, you need to know, that `count(), sum(), min(), max()` plus other columns request a `group by` and inside of it should be taken this `plus columns`. This column name just doesn't exists. And that could be seen  only by you in your DB.